# A word that means 'a bit'

Tags: single-word-requests

Okay, I am writing a novel and I want to know a single word that means 'a bit'. The book is set in the 1840s so preferably should be a bit dated. See, I used it again! Please help! The sentence it is used in is: 'a bit like their own'. The speaker hasn't had any education and it is set in the north of the United States of America. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Can you give an example sentence where you would use the word?

Comment: And where's the novel set, what are the speaker's education and community?

Comment: *Somewhat* dated.

Answer (score 2):

In your second usage (as an adverb) it could be 'slightly'.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to suggest ‘somewhat’, but if the speaker is supposed to be largely uneducated and based in North America, perhaps “kinda” would be better?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something dated, here's three from early 1800's slang: 'a flash', 'a tit-bit', and 'a snap'. All describe a small portion/amount of something.